# Сakephp оформить запрос в finder

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Ребята, помогите записать и выполнить данный запрос в finder cakephp 3.5.10

```
select user_id, GRP, MIN(time) as Start, MAX(time) as End
  from (select user_id, time,
       @grp:=@grp+if(time>@prev+interval 30 minute,1,0) as GRP,
       @prev:=time
  from user_log, (select @prev:=NULL, @grp:=1) X
 order by time) A
 group by GRP
```

в итоге нужно группировать результат по user_id.

*Ниже структура таблицы, для удобства*
[image: Adminer]

Спасибо

Comment: вы лучше сделайте подзапрос свой представлением в БД, таскать все эти mysql-переменные в пхп код  не очень красиво. а уже ко вьюшке пишите обычный ORM запрос, через фаиндеры либо через произвольный билдер (чтобы не строить модель ко вьюшке).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Построил запрос в контроллере, может кому пригодиться!

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$details = $connection
    ->newQuery()
    ->select(['Users.name', 'user_id', 'start' => 'work_period, MIN(datetime)', 'end' => 'MAX(datetime)', 'TIMEDIFF(MAX(datetime)', 'result' => 'MIN(datetime))'])
    ->from('(select user_id, datetime, @workperiod:=@workperiod+if(datetime>@prev+interval 15 minute,1,0) as work_period,@prev:=datetime from user_log, (select @prev:=NULL, @workperiod:=1) X order by datetime) A INNER JOIN users as Users ON Users.id = user_id')
    ->where(['datetime LIKE' => $date."%"])
    ->group(['work_period', 'user_id'])
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Comment: с таким успехом лучше бы вы его просто в `$connection->execute()` запихали целиком

Comment: Мне нужно условие добавлять